# How to disable navigation button when reached last record?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component that has a navigation button, when the component is used the button is not getting disabled when reached last record. Please suggest a solution.

Vue Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
     <div class="sliderArrowWrapper">
       <div class="customArrowLeft" :id="`${navigateID}Left`" style="margin-right: 10px" >
        <span class="arrowText">Prev</span>
       </div>
       <div class="customArrow" :id="`${navigateID}Right`" style="margin-left: 10px" >
        <span class="arrowText">Next</span>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['navigateID']
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is 'last record'? The code you've shown has nothing about it - no slots, nothing. If it's a wrapper for some collection, you might consider using a separate component for that, and connect this component with props of your slider-wrapper so that you'll be able to disable/enable these arrows when position changes.

Comment: You also speak of a button that isn't getting disabled, but haven't provided code for anything clickable in your example. Are you using a `<button>`? A `<div @click="doSomething">`?